# What code should I change to get the flare.json uncollapsible on first load?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to know, what code should I change to make the flare.json doesn't collapse when first on load?

It's the normal flare.json on-load

[image]

I need the result like this

[image]

What code should I change so I can get the result as the second screenshot? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution to this. Assuming you're using [Mike's example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083), the `collapse` method is designed to be recursive. By default, the tree is expanded when loaded. The program calls the line `root.children.forEach(collapse);` to collapse it. But note that this only calls collapse on the children, and does not collapse the root itself.

Thus, to get the behavior you want, simply change that line to:

```
collapse(root);
```

And it will load up with the root also being collapsed.